# Where do I change the setting in Eclipse so that it would generate serialVersionUID for Serializable classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, compiler-warnings, serialversionuid

I want Eclipse to generate a `serialVersionUID` for classes that implement `Serializable`.

However, my Eclipse instance does not throw me a warning or an error when I create a  class that implements `Serializable`. Also, it does not give an suggestion about adding a generated `serialVersionUID`. Where do I change the required setting?

Comment: Did you add `@SuppressWarnings("serial")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn on warning for `Serializable` class without a serialVersionID, go to `Window` > `Preference` > `Java` > `Compiler` > `Errors/Warnings` and search for `Serializable class without a serialVersionID`. Set that to Error or Warning based on your preference.

Once warning for "*[class] does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long*" are thrown you can click on the serialization class and press `CTRL + 1`.

Comment: @Sujay- I am sorry I could not mark the answer as useful. I do not have enough Reputation to do so.

Comment: @vk239: I see a tick though :) that's helpful!