# The most oversold java warning?

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I change the setting in Eclipse so that it would generate serialVersionUID for Serializable classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102269/where-do-i-change-the-setting-in-eclipse-so-that-it-would-generate-serialversion)

What is with this *"The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long"* warning that keeps bugging me for well over a decade? I want neither polluting my code with suppress warning nor extra garbage constants. Is there Eclipse setting "Don't bother me with those serialized warnings (I might reconsider this decision if I ever trip over this pitfall)"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146715/use-the-serialversionuid-or-suppress-warnings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window - Preferences. Type "serialVersionUID" into the filter box on the left. Select the highlighted node in the tree. Then type "serialVersionUID" in the filter box on the right. Choose "Ignore" in the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, you do not have to worry about this warning.  However, here is a brief summary about what this is and how you can PROPERLY fix it

[SerialVersionUID Explanation](http://io.typepad.com/eben_hewitt_on_java/2005/10/explicitly_set_.html)